# What's an appropriate way to setup consumer driven contract testing for django api and react clients?

Tags: django, reactjs, testing

I just learned a new term called [consumer driven contract testing](https://www.thoughtworks.com/radar/techniques/consumer-driven-contract-testing).

I was thinking maybe it can help me solve my problem with writing tests for a django api provider and react frontend architecture project.

The frontend and the Django API backend are in separate repos and have their own unit tests.

However, once in a while there will be error because the frontend is assuming some fields that are not returned by the Django service backend.

I initially thought about writing end to end test, but they are slow to run and highly brittle.

I found this consumer driven contract testing and it sounds like the right thing. But when i google around, i cannot find anything suitable. Even [Pact](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-python) seems to be solely for just converting the contract to consumer tests.

What's a suitably easy way to have consumer driven contract testing for this scenario?

Answer (score 2):

Kim, sounds like you're looking for API integration tests and not really end-to-end.

As you said, the value of using pact is in getting contracts that can be validated by the providers. Pacts run exactly like your unit tests do. If you follow pact steps for your front end app you will end up writing unit tests calling the provider (your django API), establishing the requests and the responses you expect from each call.

Pact by default starts a mock server to which it will point the requests made by the pact tests in your react front end app (your consumer tests). Those tests, once executed, generate pact files in json. The pact files should then be executed by your API so the API knows it's not breaking the front end.

Looks like you're trying to use pact for integration testing. Pact is not the right tool for that, as all you need is a test that calls your django API to verify the responses. There is no easy way to get contract testing up and running full steam. It is easy to get started, though, but you won't have all you need without the right setups, and it involves devops work, too.

What I do whenever I need to test the integration with APIs outside pact is:

- make sure the API calls are isolated in methods in such a way that it's easy to unit test each individual API method calls you need; This is too easy to miss, and it leads to complicated, unreliable tests as you end up having to put a lot of logic inside your test cases just to make them return the responses you need;
- create a test calling that method, which will then call your API and give you the response you need;

Quick example:
Let's say you have a functionality that allows users to create a profile.
The logic is all in a function named createNewUserProfile

- calls GET /user passing a user id to see if the user exists
- calls GET /location to get user location info so you can add to the user profile
- calls POST /user passing user info to your backend to create the user
- returns the response from either the GET or POST, depending on which one gets called

This method contains all your logic. So you should break it down into

- one that does getUser and calls GET /user
- one that does getCurrentLocation and calls GET /location
- one that does createUser calling POST /user with the data you have.
- refactor createNewUserProfile to call the methods listed above.

Then you would have one API integration test for each getUser, getCurrentLocation, createUser, and you won't need one for the broader createNewUserProfile, as it would be much harder to find out what fails if you have several calls surrounded by business logic.

Please tell me if the example is not good enough, feel free to give us more examples so I can help with more detailed info.

Good luck!

Comment: So under what circustances do I use consumer driven contract testing? can give an eaxmple?

Comment: Sure. You use a consumer-driven contract test whenever your app consumes another service. E.g. your app consumes a movies API via GET /movies. As a consumer, you want to make sure that a call to GET /movie will respond with a list of movies. For that, in your app you write a unit test using pact stating that when a GET request to /movies is made, you expect the API to respond with { movies: [{title: 'gone with the wind', publishDate: '1939'}, {title: 'wizard of oz', publishDate: '1939'}]}. Your test will generate a pact (the contract), and that contract will be then validated by a pact broker.

Comment: @KimStacks choose one simple API call to any APIs your using, then try writing the unit test using pact in your front end app for that API call and let me know what challenges you face. Let me know how it goes and I can help you go from there. If you need more help to get started like 'should I start in the react app or the django app' just post it here and I can definitely help you there.

Answer (score 0):

Consumer Driven Contract Testing is just one way of enforcing an API Contract between a consumer and provider.

Also IMHO Integration and End To End Tests are very late feedback cycle, slow and expensive to maintain.

In order to keep your Consumer and Provider working well together without actually going through End to End or Integration Tests you can leverage [Contract Driven Development](https://specmatic.in/contract_driven_development.html). Here is a short [explainer video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3HPgpvd8MGg&list=PL9Z-JgiTsOYRERcsy9o3y6nsi5yK3IB_w).

In Contract Driven Development you will

- Represent your Django API backend in an API Specification such as [OpenAPI](https://www.openapis.org/)
- Leverage this API Specification as an Executable Contract

  - Consumer Side - Leverage your API Specification as Stub to emulate the Provider. Write a component test for frontend and wire up your frontend to talk to this stub thereby independently testing your frontend. Please see [anatomy of component test](https://youtu.be/U5Agz-mvYIU?t=995)
  - Provider Side - Leverage the API Specification as "Contract as Test" to verify if the Django API backend is adhering to the API Specification
- By keeping both consumer and provider as per the common API Specification you can guarantee that they will work well together without having to always wait for integration or end to end tests for identifying contract compatibility issues.

Disclosure: I am the CTO at [Specmatic](https://specmatic.in/)